# Does $\mathcal{F}(U)_P = \mathcal{F}_P$ hold for $P \in U$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules on a scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. I'm curious if the following equality holds for $U \subset X$ open and $P \in U$ (resp. $P \in \text{Specm}\ \mathcal{O}_X(U)$):
$$\mathcal{F}(U)_P = \mathcal{F}_P$$
The LHS is the localization of the $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-module $\mathcal{F}(U)$ at the maximal ideal $P$ and the RHS is the stalk at the point $P \in U$.

Maybe you need some assumptions on $\mathcal{F}$ or $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, feel free to add them in your answer. Can someone give me a rigorous proof of the above or link some reference? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's true if $U$ is affine and $\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent. Otherwise, think about $X=U=\mathbb{P}^1$ and the structure sheaf.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Could you please give me some reference?

Comment: For which part?

Comment: @AlexYoucis For "It's true if $U$ is affine and $\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent."

Comment: I don't know a specific reference off-hand. It should be in any algebraic geometry text.

Comment: Regarding a reference: Hartshorne Ch. II section 5 (I think), where quasi-coh. sheave are first discussed.  You may need to read b/w the lines slightly to deduce your statement from what is there.